# how to read a CSV and get every column, then calculating Mean,Standard Deviation,variance,min and max,then create or write the news values on CSV file

Tags: csv, junit, normalization

I have a question from a company, the question says I have to implement z-score and minMaxScaling to read a csv file and do some calculations with BigDecimal so, I create a new class that implements Normalizer interface to deal with z-score and minMaxScaling so I will add the code with the test cases

NormalizerTest class:

```
@Test
public void givenMarksCSVFileToScale_whenMarkColumnIsZScored_thenNewCSVFileIsGeneratedWithAdditionalZScoreColumn() throws IOException {
    String filename = "marks.csv";
    Path induction = Files.createTempDirectory("induction");
    String columnName = "mark";
    Path csvPath = induction.resolve(filename);
    Path destPath = induction.resolve("marks_scaled.csv");
    copyFile("/marks.csv", csvPath);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(csvPath));

    Normalizer normalizer = normalizer();
    ScoringSummary summary = normalizer.zscore(csvPath, destPath, columnName);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(summary, "the returned summary is null");

    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("66.00"), summary.mean(), "invalid mean");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("16.73"), summary.standardDeviation(), "invalid standard deviation");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("280.00"), summary.variance(), "invalid variance");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("65.00"), summary.median(), "invalid median");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("40.00"), summary.min(), "invalid min value");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("95.00"), summary.max(), "invalid maximum value");

    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(destPath), "the destination file does not exists");
    Assertions.assertFalse(Files.isDirectory(destPath), "the destination is not a file");

    List<String> generatedLines = Files.readAllLines(destPath);
    Path assertionPath = copyFile("/marks_z.csv", induction.resolve("marks_z.csv"));
    List<String> expectedLines = Files.readAllLines(assertionPath);
    assertLines(generatedLines, expectedLines);
}

@Test
public void givenEmployeesCSVFileToScale_whenSalaryColumnIsZScored_thenNewCSVFileIsGeneratedWithAdditionalZScoreColumn() throws IOException {
    String filename = "employees.csv";
    Path induction = Files.createTempDirectory("induction");
    String columnName = "salary";
    Path csvPath = induction.resolve(filename);
    Path destPath = induction.resolve("employees_scaled.csv");
    copyFile("/employees.csv", csvPath);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(csvPath));

    Normalizer normalizer = normalizer();
    ScoringSummary summary = normalizer.zscore(csvPath, destPath, columnName);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(summary, "the returned summary is null");

    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1702.00"), summary.mean(), "invalid mean");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("785.19"), summary.standardDeviation(), "invalid standard deviation");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("616523.00"), summary.variance(), "invalid variance");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1758.00"), summary.median(), "invalid median");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("299.00"), summary.min(), "invalid min value");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2965.00"), summary.max(), "invalid maximum value");

    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(destPath), "the destination file does not exists");
    Assertions.assertFalse(Files.isDirectory(destPath), "the destination is not a file");

    List<String> generatedLines = Files.readAllLines(destPath);
    Path assertionPath = copyFile("/employees_z.csv", induction.resolve("employees_z.csv"));
    List<String> expectedLines = Files.readAllLines(assertionPath);
    assertLines(generatedLines, expectedLines);
}

 @Test
public void givenMarksCSVFileToScale_whenMarkColumnIsMinMaxScaled_thenNewCSVFileIsGeneratedWithAdditionalMinMaxScoreColumn() throws IOException {
    String filename = "marks.csv";
    Path induction = Files.createTempDirectory("induction");
    String columnName = "mark";
    Path csvPath = induction.resolve(filename);
    Path destPath = induction.resolve("marks_scaled.csv");
    copyFile("/marks.csv", csvPath);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(csvPath));

    Normalizer normalizer = normalizer();
    ScoringSummary summary = normalizer.minMaxScaling(csvPath, destPath, columnName);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(summary, "the returned summary is null");

    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("66.00"), summary.mean(), "invalid mean");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("16.73"), summary.standardDeviation(), "invalid standard deviation");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("280.00"), summary.variance(), "invalid variance");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("65.00"), summary.median(), "invalid median");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("40.00"), summary.min(), "invalid min value");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("95.00"), summary.max(), "invalid maximum value");

    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(destPath), "the destination file does not exists");
    Assertions.assertFalse(Files.isDirectory(destPath), "the destination is not a file");

    List<String> generatedLines = Files.readAllLines(destPath);
    Path assertionPath = copyFile("/marks_mm.csv", induction.resolve("marks_mm.csv"));
    List<String> expectedLines = Files.readAllLines(assertionPath);
    assertLines(expectedLines, generatedLines);
}

@Test
public void givenEmployeesCSVFileToScale_whenSalaryColumnIsMinMaxScaled_thenNewCSVFileIsGeneratedWithAdditionalMinMaxScoreColumn() throws IOException {
    String filename = "employees.csv";
    Path induction = Files.createTempDirectory("induction");
    String columnName = "salary";
    Path csvPath = induction.resolve(filename);
    Path destPath = induction.resolve("employees_scaled.csv");
    copyFile("/employees.csv", csvPath);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(csvPath));

    Normalizer normalizer = normalizer();
    ScoringSummary summary = normalizer.minMaxScaling(csvPath, destPath, columnName);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(summary, "the returned summary is null");

    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1702.00"), summary.mean(), "invalid mean");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("785.19"), summary.standardDeviation(), "invalid standard deviation");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("616523.00"), summary.variance(), "invalid variance");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("1758.00"), summary.median(), "invalid median");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("299.00"), summary.min(), "invalid min value");
    Assertions.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("2965.00"), summary.max(), "invalid maximum value");

    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(destPath), "the destination file does not exists");
    Assertions.assertFalse(Files.isDirectory(destPath), "the destination is not a file");

    List<String> generatedLines = Files.readAllLines(destPath);
    Path assertionPath = copyFile("/employees_mm.csv", induction.resolve("employees_mm.csv"));
    List<String> expectedLines = Files.readAllLines(assertionPath);
    assertLines(expectedLines, generatedLines);
}

private final Path copyFile(String resource, Path path) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource)) {
        try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(path)) {
            int b;
            while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(b);
            }
        }
    }
    return path;
}

private void assertLines(List<String> generatedLines, List<String> expectedLines) {
    Assertions.assertTrue(generatedLines.size() == expectedLines.size(), "lines are not identical");
    for (int i = 0; i < generatedLines.size(); i++) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedLines.get(i), generatedLines.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

ScoringSummary interface:

```
public interface ScoringSummary {
public BigDecimal mean();

public BigDecimal standardDeviation();

public BigDecimal variance();

public BigDecimal median();

public BigDecimal min();

public BigDecimal max();
```

}

Comment: What's the roadblock?

Comment: it is just a question have its own CSV file and I have to read every CSV file by column and calculate  Mean, Standard Deviation, variance,min, and max, then create or write the news values on the CSV file by using normalize z-score and minMaxScaling

Comment: the roadblock, I write my code but there were 2 cases passed, 2  cases that failed, and 2 cases error